# XYPlot doesn't draw all points correctly

Tags: java, android, androidplot

I'm trying to display 550 data points with periodic peaks (the flat line is `61`). The problem is, that androidplot isn't drawing all the points correctly! From my log:

```
ECG I values 61,61,62,63,62,61,61,61,61,67,71,68,61,53,61,61,61,61,61,61,61,61,62,63,64,64,64,63,62,61,61,61
```

I've got the rangeboundaries set to `plot.setRangeBoundaries(0,100, BoundaryMode.AUTO);`, but as you can see, the peaks never drop to the `53` data point. I can see this lower point sometimes, but it gets smoothed out a fraction of a second later (as you can see in the screenshot).

My line and point formatter is:

```
LineAndPointFormatter lapf = new LineAndPointFormatter(p.color, null, null, null);
lapf.getLinePaint().setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
lapf.getLinePaint().setStrokeWidth(1);
```

I've tried with the both `Paint.Join.ROUND` and `Paint.Join.BEVEL` and got the same effect. I've also used the debugger to check that `53` is being inserted into the series.

[image]

**EDIT**

After some debugging, it looks like my pulse loop thread is wrong:

```
while (keepRunning) {
    for (PulseXYSeries j : series) {
        for (int k = 0; k < j.plotStep; k++) {
            int at = (j.position + k) % j.getSize();        
            if (j.pulsing) {
                if (j.pulsePosition == j.pulseValues.size() - 1) {
                    j.pulsing = false;
                    j.pulsePosition = 0;
                } else {
                    try {
                        int pulseVal = j.pulseValues.get(j.pulsePosition);
                        j.setY(pulseVal,at); 
                        j.pulsePosition += 1;
                    } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                        j.pulsePosition = 0;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                j.setY(j.pulseValues.get(0), at); 
                long currTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                if (currTime - j.getLastPulse() >= j.getPulseDelay()) {
                    j.pulsing = true;
                    j.setLastPulse(currTime);
                }
            }
            j.remove(((at + j.eraserSize) % j.getSize()));
        }
        j.position = (j.position + 1) % j.getSize(); // fixed it by changing +1 to + j.plotStep
    }
    Thread.sleep(delay);
}
```

My custom series looks like:

```
private class PulseXYSeries implements XYSeries {
    private List<Integer> pulseValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private int pulsePerMinute;
    public int pulsePosition;
    public int position;
    private ArrayList<Integer> values;
    private String title;
    private long lastPulse;
    public boolean pulsing = false;
    public int eraserSize = 20;
    public int plotStep = 3;
}
```

Comment: so it gets drawn as lowerpoint but afterwards it becomes flat (61)?

Comment: Does the screenshot shows 7 times the ECG I values that you have listed in the beginning, or there are also other points used for drawing that (screenshot)? In short: should the 7 heartbeats look the same?

Comment: @FrancisFuerte The low point isn't always drawn. the plot is constantly being updated, the series given in the question is shown periodically, with a flat line in between.

Comment: @helleye the 7 ECG I values are the same (so I expect all the pulses to look the same), yes. The only other point is the flat section which is the first point in the ECG series.

Comment: have you tried lowering the stroke Width?

Comment: @FrancisFuerte I lowered it to `0.1f`, I still get the same effect. I also tried lowering the number of points on the domain (so less pulses appear).

Comment: I've updated my code with where I think the error is

Comment: @Jonno have you tried making letting it stay at 1.. but doubling the values of the ecg.. like 2 of each so its slower.. lets say 61,61,62,63,62,61,61.. should be 61,61,61,61,62,62,63,63,62,62,61,61,61,61,61

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks for the help, the problem was that it wasn't putting all the values into the series, because my loop skipped some.